# Checkout failed with svnkit 1.8 embedded : no checksum is recorded for this file

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, svnkit

Since the beginning of the week I am dealing with a strange error.
I have an application using svnkit 1.8 which failed to checkout a project from svn. The following error is raised :

`svn: E155017: Cant install "a file" from pristine store, because no checksum is recorded for this file`

After some debugging I find that this error is returned by the svn server. Note that this error appears since I upgrade svnkit to 1.8 from 1.7.

Here is my current configuration :

- My application with svnkit 1.8
- The svn server with svn 1.6
- Cntlm on my pc to use a proxy
- Ubuntu 14.04 with svn 1.8

If I check out the project in comand line it works.

And the last but not least when I start my app inside Intellij everything works fine!

I don't know what to do anymore.
Thanks for any help.

Edit: I answer to myself.

It seems that my problem is related with the new ".svn behavior" introduced with svn 1.7.
Activating [svnkit log](http://svnkit.com/kb/user-guide-debug-logs.html) show me that it fails to find wc.db... So intead of checkout my file I use `SVNRepository.getFile()` to read it.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem very quickly.
We updated our SVN Server to 1.8 so I updated the older versions of `svnkit-1.7.8.jar`, `svnkit-javahl16-1.7.8.jar` and `svnkit-cli-1.7.8` to version 1.8.6.

After compiling and testing, I ran into the same issue as mentioned above.

The problem was simple. I did not update any other svnkit dependencies such as the following three libraries:

`jna-3.4.0.jar` to `jna-4.1.0.jar`
`sqljet-1.1.6.jar` to `sqljet-1.1.10`
`sequence-library-1.0.2.jar` to `sequence-library-1.0.2.jar`.

After updating these libraries to the newer ones (I took them from the svnkit standalone version which I downloaded [here](http://svnkit.com/download.php)) it works perfectly fine.
It seems like svnkit does not check any dependency versions so there is no error thrown when an outdated library is used.

Comment: Good idea but for me svnkit dependencies are managed by ivy. So svnkit 1.8.5 has his dependencies correctly retrieved. I use svnkit 1.8.5 which needs jna 3.5.2 unlike svnkit which needs jna 4.1.0. Maybe my problem was linked to the jna version...